# java - get the result from the shell

Tags: java

I want to make 70 commands(cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio62_pi10/value) witch ask for a value. The command returns 0 or 1 as return value. The first three times it works, but then I got an exception (java.lang.NumberFormatException).
I search through the net and found that it could be, that null will returned from the command or the command needs more time to return the value. I have no idea how I can fix this problem.

code:

```
System.out.print("Hello from a thread\n");
int currantValue = -2;

    for(int i = 0; i< PinManager.pinList.size(); i++ ){
        String method = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            currantValue = -1;
            //System.out.println(i);
            commandString = "cat " + " /sys/class/gpio/" + PinManager.pinList.get(i).getFolderName() + "/value";
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec(commandString);

            
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            currantValue = (int)Integer.parseInt(stdInput.readLine());


            System.out.print("  > Methode = " + method + " : " + commandString + "       currentValue = " + currantValue + "\n"); //consolen output for testing
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + method);
        }

        if(PinManager.pinList.get(i).getOldValue() != currantValue){
            //wenn pin sich geändert hat
        }
    }
```

output:

> Hello from a thread
>
> Methode = Watching : cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio60_pi11/value       currentValue = 0
>
> Methode = Watching : cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio61_pi13/value       currentValue = 0
>
> Methode = Watching : cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio62_pi10/value       currentValue = 0
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: nullWatching
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: nullWatching
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: nullWatching
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: nullWatching
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: nullWatching

Comment: What is the value you get in stdInput.readLine() ?

Comment: how can you decide when the cmd has finish ? you need to get the promt to see that you have finish reading . you can also move the result into a file and then read the file

Comment: The value could be 1 and 0.

Comment: It works with linux.

Comment: I need the output from the shell, what I can see. With the command I can ask the value of a digital pin.